# How to change text direction in legend using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm trying to put a legend to my plot but it is aligned from top to bottom, how can I make the text in legend horizontal? Thanks in advance.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sp=ax.contourf(x1line, x2line, pgrid)
plt.colorbar(sp)
ax.legend('label1')
```

[Plot looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqAZM.png)

Comment: This might help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-position-and-align-a-matplotlib-figure-legend#:~:text=To%20position%20and%20align%20a%20matplotlib%20figure%20legend%2C,and%20make%20horizontal%20alignment%20of%20the%20legend%20elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ax.legend` expects a list of strings as its argument.  Try this:

```
ax.legend(['label1'])
```

Since you passed a string (vs. a list) the string is treated as an iterable and each character becomes its own row in the legend.